# How to populate an array from detailViewController and return to masterViewController in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have a `tableView` from which I navigate to a 'viewController' ie `PassengerInfoViewController` in which I have a form.I fill up the form , make a `dictionary` out of it and add it to a `NSMutableArray`.

So when I am going back to the `tableView' I would like to pass this array and then reload the`tableView` with the filled array.

So here's what I am doing : -

```
  //navigate to the form
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  PassengerInfoViewController *pivc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PassengerInfoViewController"];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:pivc animated:YES];

}

 //After filling up the form 

 -(void)goBackToPassengerDetails:(UIButton*)sender{

   NSString *title = self.titleTextField.text;
   NSString *fname = self.firstNameTextField.text;
   NSString *lname =self.lastNameTextField.text;
   NSString *ageStr = self.ageTextField.text;

   NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
   [dict setValue:title forKey:@"title"];
   [dict setValue:fname forKey:@"firstName"];
   [dict setValue:lname forKey:@"lastName"];
   [dict setValue:ageStr forKey:@"age"];
   Passenger *passengerObj = [Passenger sharedInstance]; //Singleton

   [passengerObj.passengerDetailArray addObject:dict];

    PassengerDetailsViewController *pdc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PassengerDetailsViewController"];
[pdc getPassengerinfo:passengerObj.passengerDetailArray];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Once I navigate back I reload the table view.However `celForRow` method doesn't populate new values.

```
 -(void)getPassengerinfo:(NSMutableArray*)arr{
  passenger_infoArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  passenger_infoArray = arr;
  NSLog(@"Passenger Info Array : %@", passenger_infoArray);//Shows array of dictionaries

  [passengerInfoTableView reloadData];
}
```

My `cellForRow` method looks like this:

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   //Not called when I am doing reload data
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil)
   {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];

   }
   NSLog(@"Table view array  : %@",passenger_infoArray); 
   if (passenger_infoArray.count>0) {

    NSString *temp= [[passenger_infoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"firstName"];
    cell.textLabel.text = temp;
   }else{

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Passenger %ld", (long)indexPath.row+1];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"user.png"];

   }
     return cell;

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data using

1. Delegates
2. Notifications
3. Properties
4. Global variables

Using Delegates is good practice, and last two are not preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data to previous view controller by using delegate method

In **PassengerInfoViewController.h** add below code just above of your `import` statement

```
@protocol passengerInfoViewControllerdelegate <NSObject>
     -(void)sendData:(NSMutableArray *)arrData; 
@end
```

After this create one property, as shown below

```
@property(nonatomic,assign)id delegate;
```

Now, in **PassengerInfoViewController.m** synthesize the property and after that

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [delegate sendData:yourArray];
}
```

Now in `tableview`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PassengerInfoViewController *pivc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PassengerInfoViewController"];

    pivc.delegate = self;  //Add this line to your code

   [self.navigationController pushViewController:pivc animated:YES];
}
```

Now, it's time to implement delegate method which we created in viewcontroller

```
-(void)sendData:(NSMutableArray *)arrData
{
      passenger_infoArray = arrData;
     [passengerInfoTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Well the reason I used a singleton array was that, I wanted to keep the previous values too ie if I have added a dictionary to it previously.I just want to add new dictionary to the array.

Comment: then in that case you have to store the previous array either in prefrence or in database

Comment: I am getting the array when I return now.But even after calling reloadData on table view the cellFor row is not reading the code where I am populating it from array.Any idea why?See my updated question.

Comment: Try to reload table from viewwillappear method

Answer (score 0):

Old way to do this was using delegates. Better way to do this is via an unwind segue because there's much less code and you don't have to create a protocol.

Once your form completes, your PDC should call `[self performSegue:@"theNameOfTheUnwindSegueeYouCreateInTheStoryboard"]`. Then, in your PDC's `prepareForSegue` method, get the `destinationViewController` property from the `storyboardSegue` parameter - this is your VC containing the Table View. Set whatever model property you're using to back the table view - in your case it looks to be the `passenger_infoArray` object, which you'll have to make mutable if isn't already and also expose publicly if it isn't already.

Comment: I am getting the array when I return from the 'passengerInfoVC` with prepoulated values also.But even after calling reloadData my cellForRow method is not called.

Comment: In the scenario I outlined you'd want to call reloadData when the viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear methods. Try setting breakpoints to see when those are called.